# Developer Uber API - Link Organization

Tags: uber-api

I hope this is the right place to ask this question

So I want to create application in developer uber console. After I choose API Suite, next step is to link or create organization. As I have no organization, I want to create one, but it does not allows me to do. After population all fields to create organization button "Link organization" is always grayed out. Picture is attached.

Any help would me very much appreciated

[Screenshot of image where you can see that all fields are populated, but still cannot submit it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZziUP.png)

I have tried with all 3 api options: Uber Pay, Eats Marketplace, and Other
I also tested with other uber account
I try to first create application, but again button "Create" is grayed out

Comment: did you use an actual adress? It says "adress should contain at least 5 words", your input is one word.

Comment: @defaultUsernameN thanks for pointing that out. I haven't noticed that, and my address was only 4 works. So that is the reason why it wasn;t working